# Countable choice for countable subfamily

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

**Axiom of Countable Choice (CC)** states that for every countable family $\left\{A_i\right\}_{i=1}^\infty$ of nonempty sets there exists *choice function* $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ such that $f(i) \in A_i$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Consider the following axiom strongly related to the above axiom:

For every countably infinite family $\left\{A_i\right\}_{i=1}^\infty$ of nonempty sets there exists countably infinite subfamily $\left\{A_{i_k}\right\}_{k=1}^\infty$ such that $\left\{A_{i_k}\right\}_{k=1}^\infty$ has *choice function* i.e. there exists $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_{i_k}$ such that $f(k) \in A_{i_k}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let's call it **Axiom of Countable Choice for Countable Subfamily (CCCS)**.

Of course **CC** implies **CCCS**. But I wonder if **CCCS** is strongly weaker than **CC** or equivalent to **CC**.

I can't imagine being the first person to come up with the idea of **CCCS**, so probably there is literature which consider this kind of *choice axiom* or maybe it's unnaturally to consider such an axiom. I'm amateur in that sort of set theory. What do you think? Maybe someone knows proper literature?

Comment: Also known as **Partial** Countable Choice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are equivalent. Given a countable family $B_i$ of nonempty sets, let $A_i=\prod_{j=1}^iB_j$. That these are nonempty is provable in ZF (we only use finite products). Now for any choice function $f$ with $f(k)\in A_{i_k}$, since $i_k\geq k$, projecting $f(k)$ onto the $k$-th coordinate of $A_{i_k}=\prod_{j=1}^{i_k}B_j$ gives a choice function for the $B_i$.

I don't know a reference for this result, but I have seen similar arguments when establishing various equivalents of countable choice for subsets of $\mathbb R$, so I can't take full credit for the idea.

Comment: Thanks! Quite simple proof. They are equivalent so that's enough for me (I don't need any reference).